# App identifiers vs 'lite' and 'pro' versions

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, app-store, provisioning-profile

we have had our free iPhone app on AppStore for a month or so, and we are now updating it. In our update we have added a lot of support for new stuff, i.e iPad-support, and it's a pretty heavy update. In our existing app, we have a lot of ads everywhere, and we now want to upload this new version as a 'pro' version alongside the other one insted of updating the old one, giving the users a choice between the old free 'ad-filled' app, and the new $0.99 'ad-less' and upgraded app. We are still using our same Xcode-project, and we are wondering if we need to change any app-identifiers or provisioning profiles or notification keys or anything like that? Our push-service is to be used for the same to both apps, so if we don't have to add an extra .pem etc, we don't want to..

Comment: I think lite and pro versions are submitted as seperate apps.

Comment: @Almo But does this mean we HAVE to change the app identifier and provisioning profiles?

Comment: I thought it did, but I have only published one iPhone game. I can't see how else the two apps could be distringuished from one another in the store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to have different apps (been "lite" and "pro" doesn't mean much on AppStore) you need different identifiers and so different provisioning profiles.
the easier way is to create a new target in XCode cloning the existing one and then modify it.
I've no direct experience related to the push part, but I suppose different provisioning ends in different .pem
You may consider Using inApp purchase to have just one app and let the user buy the banner-free upgrade from the app itself...